# scrape Shopee API v4

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, web-deployment, shopee

I have a final project where the data I want to retrieve is through scraping data on shopee, but I have a problem when I scrape shopee on a hidden API, when I try it on the Insomnia script the script runs, but when I try it on local or google colab script this is an error.

How can I fix this?

```
    import requests
    import json
    headers = {
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'cookie': 'REC_T_ID=e67c02b5-ae54-11ec-b368-46ac8e8cc9d8; SPC_F=KrJ9Ck0EYC252EWJ3FSH5QFNzjmvng6O; SPC_IA=-1; _gcl_au=1.1.459910866.1654678938; _fbp=fb.2.1654678939550.956784750; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; SPC_CLIENTID=S3JKOUNrMEVZQzI1jkqfwanvqrwehsep; _gcl_aw=GCL.1660529943.Cj0KCQjwuuKXBhCRARIsAC-gM0g5RPYu1Cfx0PZbXHrR5qqd7JqgFEy4XrCAxXEGFD4quU2tORTIR9caAsVdEALw_wcB; _gac_UA-61904553-8=1.1660529949.Cj0KCQjwuuKXBhCRARIsAC-gM0g5RPYu1Cfx0PZbXHrR5qqd7JqgFEy4XrCAxXEGFD4quU2tORTIR9caAsVdEALw_wcB; _med=refer; _gid=GA1.3.792417909.1660891119; csrftoken=Hk3UgpYhG30zu0CO9Vhk2OIKptWNBS0g; _QPWSDCXHZQA=9be12e07-9c49-426e-e0d8-01a11f73956b; AMP_TOKEN=%24NOT_FOUND; __LOCALE__null=ID; _dc_gtm_UA-61904553-8=1; SPC_T_ID="uXbSXytLbRMSr+KtQpRkW7f5FHiriPO+CdAryBv6THa5ljtJhfxKSiI5g2Ps2Fl4eILJBWgkAYeR+c0hO4843b12KCXHt56jNWASfgA5Uq8="; SPC_U=616200160; SPC_T_IV="eB95as87FjhL8HoasAA0kw=="; _ga_KK6LLGGZNQ=GS1.1.1660961596.8.0.1660961596.0.0.0; SPC_R_T_ID=uXbSXytLbRMSr+KtQpRkW7f5FHiriPO+CdAryBv6THa5ljtJhfxKSiI5g2Ps2Fl4eILJBWgkAYeR+c0hO4843b12KCXHt56jNWASfgA5Uq8=; SPC_R_T_IV=eB95as87FjhL8HoasAA0kw==; SPC_T_ID=uXbSXytLbRMSr+KtQpRkW7f5FHiriPO+CdAryBv6THa5ljtJhfxKSiI5g2Ps2Fl4eILJBWgkAYeR+c0hO4843b12KCXHt56jNWASfgA5Uq8=; SPC_T_IV=eB95as87FjhL8HoasAA0kw==; SPC_SI=id+yYgAAAABBUWdBaGJJRaEQWwAAAAAAbDFtUDZZZ2k=; SPC_ST=.aVZDcFoyVjBuUWIwUXVSUnkGCGuGI58EkFOzdykhsuSCGz0GrBWotkUiREvJO38YxTxyl3Pgbl73NUs1AmCexDhPneO/ABd8bgUkVqlhCvZTNPDPg8jv/9KaHwWagKm9FM55IY61eECu5twdRUQl9u3xgfshk26TRkvpli4dlCUZzIE0boMi5/5B/CcqUgoXsDH567+KunuKEe92wUSC1Q==; _ga=GA1.3.1352849021.1654678939; cto_bundle=ZLv7oF9EWUpOZWVHYUkyUHh0d2RBWDJvTWk5eXllWVpia1F1eXJ4RkdZcjhVZ1Q3NVRYYnE0c0hOWERsMm1tTjFER09MbmdMTW1VZG5VbkQ0MjByVnpxYlNRdk1MRk9TUGtNSzZpRzRnZFNXU1ZUVlElMkY1dXRpbGFUZm5vdjdvcklFQzk0YzBuVm1qMUJzZnRyb2xPMHpRMldVQSUzRCUzRA; _ga_SW6D8G0HXK=GS1.1.1660959836.35.1.1660961617.22.0.0; SPC_EC=U1A1Vk5JdzlVaFVYdjJRUk4fyVPKEHSso64GpvFSCO/oihfsUpaQrXO9e4XqPT/AjNQJP7hcW+o+A7chna6AIbCtFRsocFdW1x1oS3A8+pNHmK3oRTDCZe2BDyAP0cOp133wiyu0GTSCetXIhbIRwvkOTJYqOXYBGKuTW6tGY1o=; shopee_webUnique_ccd=veSMI3XpR84mDT6rWJgoWg%3D%3D%7C9xD6GCFDkurxx4Cxf%2F72oK7%2FP2ilXgSYBkzRAd4F%2BSkKrCsqCWGVzz0SHGMINBr5KgoTxt7LXhBKejCILMQlWRcetFY%3D%7ClXsfMcnYECC51PEy%7C05%7C3',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'referer':'https://shopee.co.id/Perawatan-Kecantikan-cat.11043145?page=0&ratingFilter=4',
          }
    x=0
    number_page = x*60
    url =("https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/search/search_items?by=relevancy&limit=60&match_id=11043145"
            "&newest={}&order=desc&page_type=search&rating_filter=4&scenario=PAGE_CATEGORY&version=2").format(number_page)
    y = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    y
```

**Output:**

```
{'tracking_id': '745a6f4b-0fc3-48af-b563-5a7ec483a601',
 'action_type': 2,
 'error': 90309999}
```

Comment: The cookie you're sending includes embedded identity information.  When you switch machines/browsers, the identity information doesn't match any more.  Can't you just start a new session each time and log in again?

Comment: so the cookies that are in chrome or the app testing API can't be used when creating the get API in python huh?, so I have to build cookies from the machine I will use?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  Every HTTP request stands complete alone.  When you connect to a web site for the first time, they hand you back cookies.  You are expected to provide those cookies when you call them again.  That's how they know it was you.  Chrome stores the cookies it gets in its cache.  You need to do the same.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and this useful information, I really get new knowledge from this problem.
I hope you won't get bored if I have other questions but it's still about this problem, I'm still trying to test according to your suggestions

Answer (score 6):

You can add a requests header, like this headers key af-ac-enc-dat value null, this works for me.

```
                var request = WebRequest.Create(apiURL);
                request.Headers["x-api-source"] = "pc";
                request.Headers["af-ac-enc-dat"] = "null";
                var response = request.GetResponse();
                var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                s_ResponseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic Prodata = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(s_ResponseString);
```

Comment: although you can get data from API, but wrong data. You can please check fields price, price_max, price_min,...

Comment: omg, this worked , how did you figured this out, I got the exact same data from this example endpoint: ```https://shopee.ph/api/v4/pdp/get_pc?shop_id=325399892&item_id=13542349872```, you'd just need to pass in the headers you've specified. Also it's a great practice to include cookies from your account. Please mark this as the answer OP.

Comment: @Hargun IT SOLUTION , how did you managed to figure it out to set those particular values in the headers?

Comment: Hi! it seems that after some times, passing in those headers doesn't seem to quite work anymore. It's getting the same error again based on the OP's post. How did you manage to figure it out and can we figure it out again please? Thanks!