# Scraping products from shopee using python requests returns 90309999

Tags: python, web-scraping, session, python-requests, shopee

Since 2022, I was able to scrap [shopee listings](https://shopee.com.br/search?filters=9&keyword=funko&locations=Nacional&noCorrection=true&page=0&sortBy=relevancy) using [python requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with headers `User-Agent` and `From` only. However, since last week, I've been receiving error code number ***90309999*** from `{"is_customized":false,"is_login":false,"action_type":2,"error":90309999,"tracking_id":"583f2b10-6b13-4402-8b3b-a6b8f0fead62"}`

Also, I've checked this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74333263/5465165) and added headers `x-api-source` and `af-ac-enc-dat`, but isn't working. Any suggestions?

```
from requests import Session

base_url = 'https://shopee.com.br/search?filters=9&keyword=funko&locations=Nacional&noCorrection=true&page=0&sortBy=relevancy'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Googlebot',
    'From': '',
    'af-ac-enc-dat': '',
    'x-api-source': 'pc',
}

with Session() as s:
    s.get(base_url, headers=headers)
```

Don't want to use **Selenium** or **Scrapy** for this task, thanks!

EDIT: Also, I've insert `null` to `af-ac-enc-dat` but same results are shown.

Comment: You're not using the same `af-ac-enc-dat` header value as the linked thread.  They used `"null"`, but you're using an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to scrape using the `Googlebot` user agent? How about just using a Mozilla user agent?

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0",
    "From": "",
    "af-ac-enc-dat": "",
    "x-api-source": "pc",
}

params = {
    "filters": "9",
    "keyword": "funko",
    "locations": "Nacional",
    "noCorrection": "true",
    "page": "0",
    "sortBy": "relevancy",
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get("https://shopee.com.br/search", params=params, headers=headers)
    print(response)
```

Comment: Thanks in advance, but it doesnt works as well for me, its works for you? I'm afraid I'm banned from shopee

Comment: Ah, okay, well that's not a technical problem then! Have you tried using a proxy server to get around the ban?

Comment: And since you have been banned, when you start crawling again (perhaps via a proxy) you should be **very** conservative with the number and frequency of requests in order not to get banned again!